# Issue with pandas 2.0: Assigning values to a new column after modifying the 'date_created' column causes errors

Tags: pandas

I am encountering a problem with pandas 2.0 where I'm unable to assign values to a new column after modifying the 'date_created' column. Specifically, I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Creating a simple dataframe for demonstration
data = """
date_created,value
2018-01-01 00:00:00,1
2018-02-01 00:00:00,2
2018-03-01 00:00:00,3
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
print(df)

# This line works fine
df.loc[:, 'date_created'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'date_created'], errors='raise').dt.year
print(df)

# Let's reload the data
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
```

the below code will throw exception

```
df.loc[:, 'date_created'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'date_created'], errors='raise')
df['year_created'] = df['date_created'].dt.year
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/test.py", line 26, in <module>
    df['date_created'].dt.year
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5989, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py", line 224, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/accessors.py", line 580, in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

The strange thing is that if I use the first line of code alone, everything works fine, and I confirm the problem is only after 2.0 version 1.5.3 has no error with it.

```
df.loc[:, 'date_created'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'date_created'], errors='raise').dt.year
```

Is anyone else facing a similar problem with pandas 2.0? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Convert the column to a date, then use the `.dt` accessor.

Comment: I get this warning on 1.5.3 - '<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting a new array. To retain the old behavior, use either `df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, if columns are non-unique, `df.isetitem(i, newvals)`'